# When to use std::make_shared_for_overwrite?

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, c++20

C++20 introduces new function `std::make_shared_for_overwrite()` in addition to `std::make_shared()`:
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared

Why old `make_shared` was not enough and in what situation one needs to use new function?

Comment: "Same as (2), except that the individual array elements are default-initialized."

Comment: So looks rather like a convenience function (C analogy: `malloc` vs. `calloc`).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`std::make_shared()` value initialises the object(s) it creates, which might be an unnecessary step if you intend to assign values over them later.

`std::make_shared_for_overwrite()` default initialises the object(s) it creates.

The difference only matters for (sub-)objects of fundamental types, where there is no initialiser.

`std::make_shared<int[1000][1000]>()` will allocate and zero a million `int`s
`std::make_shared_for_overwrite<int[1000][1000]>()` will allocate a million `int`s

Comment: "*The difference only matters for fundamental types, and arrays thereof.*" Or structs thereof. Or any type that's trivially default constructible.